# Inserting a formula into variable number of rows

Tags: vba, excel

So far I've managed to create a search feature that scans a column and collect rows in an Array. Then I print the array in another sheet to form a table. I do this with a number of criteria which means that I get different arrays with different sizes.

For my problem. I want to do a calculation for each Row. `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 =" = TRUNC ((RC [-5], RC [-1]) / 7) "`. How do I make a loop that adapts to how many lines there are. There are also gaps in some places.

Here is an example for how one array is printed:

```
For i = 1 To nS - 1
        Sheets("DataSheet").Select
        Union(Sheets("raw_list").Cells(arrStart(i), NameCol), Sheets("raw_list").Cells(arrStart(i), PhaseCol), Sheets("raw_list").Cells(arrStart(i), ToStartCol), Sheets("raw_list").Cells(arrStart(i), ToDefineCol), Sheets("raw_list").Cells(arrStart(i), ToMeasureCol), Sheets("raw_list").Cells(arrStart(i), ToAnalyseCol), Sheets("raw_list").Cells(arrStart(i), ToImproveDevCol), Sheets("raw_list").Cells(arrStart(i), ToImproveIndCol), Sheets("raw_list").Cells(arrStart(i), ToControlCol), Sheets("raw_list").Cells(arrStart(i), ToClosedCol)).Copy
        Cells(r, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlNone
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
        r = r + 1
    Next
```

Thankful for any help!

Edit: Added a picture to show how it looks.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are gaps, what we use at work is a simple but not-so-elegant solution which is to add markers of some sort in adjacent columns. For example, we'd add "END" or something like that in the cell of the same row but either col + 1 or col - 1 to the column you are comparing to.

Another solution would be to look if the next element is also a blank, but that will work only if you have single gaps.

Finally, the last solution I see is that when you are on a blank, use xlDown and if you are at the last cell 65535 in 2003 and near a million in 2007 if my memory serves me right, then you are finished.

Comment: Start on a bottom row cell and use xlUp?

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply. I should also have mentioned that I'm pretty new to EXCEL VBA. Added a picture to show how it looks like. So I want to make the calculations in the K:column. And where the gaps is are there supposed to be "headline" like the gray one at the top.

Your answer is probably right but I need a little more on my feet to manage to code it :/ and again, thanks

Comment: Normally you want to eliminate spaces so that you can iterate through your rows and use a Do...Loop Until variable = "". Atleast, that is the easiest method. With a loop like that you can just stop whenever you hit an empty cell. Also, there is a used rows property: ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count. You can set this equal to a variable like this -- variable = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count and tell your loop to stop when your iterator = variable.